# Use Android style Attributes in own Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use this style, which is an Android Build in Style Attribute, but it won't compile. I' am missing some kind of Import?

```
?android:attr/listItemFirstLineStyle

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" style="?android:attr/listItemFirstLineStyle" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>`
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try to remove the question mark?

`style="android:attr/listItemFirstLineStyle"`

Comment: The "?" is required when you want to access build in attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can't access all build in styles in your own projects. When you type so far in Eclipse

```
style="@android:style/"
```

and hit ctrl + enter, intellisense should give you an overview of what you can use. There are underscores in the style names, replace them by '.'...